# Parallelize Android unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

All,

Is it possible to run Android unit tests in parallel?

I've set maxParallelForks, but it doesn't actually seem to impact the time that it takes our tests to run.

I've also tried playing around with the "Fork mode" setting in the JUnit configuration, but setting it to either "Method" or "Class" both seem to slow the tests down dramatically

FYI, many of our tests are Robolectric tests.

```
testOptions.unitTests {
    all {
        testLogging {
            events "failed", "skipped"
            showStackTraces = true
            exceptionFormat = "full"
        }
        maxParallelForks = 8
        forkEvery = 20
    }
    includeAndroidResources = true
}
```

Comment: There is issue for Robolectric https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3351

Comment: [maxParallelForks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxParallelForks) - The maximum number of forked test processes to execute in parallel. The default value is 1 (no parallel test execution). It cannot exceed the value of max-workers for the current build.